# Application windows do not fit on the screen

Tags: xorg

Most of the windows does not fit on my hp-mini-210(1024*600)

[image]

the apply and close buttons are not fit on scrren and conky too !!

Answer (score 4):

Not fitting in 1024x600 with reasonable leeway for panels should be considered a bug in the applications. Please [file those bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)!

As Takkat said, you can usually alt+mouse drag the window to work around the bug. Additionally most window managers also have a 'move' action in the window menu that lets you move it with the keyboard.

Finally you can use `xrandr` to scale the window; for example,

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.2x1.5
```

would scale you to 1229x900. Crude, but effective.

If you use this last method, note that all the drivers I've tried this with get confused unless you go back to 1x1 before trying new ratios.

Comment: But screen starts to flicker during watching videos and for wobbly windows too

Comment: @Muthu it is entirely possible that your video card does not work well at a much greater resolution than the native one, especially with 3D and video going on simultaneously; that's a lot of punishment for most netbooks' puny video hardware. Try scaling your bling down when you scale the screen up.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't increase the screen resolution of your netbook. However to operate buttons that are off the lower border you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + LeftMouseButton to move the window and see missing buttons. Conky needs to display less information to make it fit.

Comment: Yes you can :-) http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/set-your-screen-resolution-higher-than-you-should-with-newrez/ Obviously, it's more of a toy (or a developer's tool), and a bit impractical for daily use. (this doesn't work on some graphics chips apparently)

Comment: Oh yes - scaling :) Thank you for pointing to this. However physical resolution will not change by this. Do you have experience with NewRez? How stable is it?

Comment: Well, on my system it works like a charm. But of course you wouldn't want to use it daily. It makes your screen look terrible, because there just aren't enough pixels. It also makes everything incredibly sluggish. I use for testing in development, works fabulously. For an emergency solution, it's absolutely brilliant. Some people on omgubuntu report that it didn't work for them, which - i guess - has to do with graphics drivers. I have a lovely Intel graphics chip, no problems there.

Comment: envy you for Intel GPU ;)

Comment: i used NewRez but screen flickers during videos !