# Ubuntu 11.10 Window Configuration

Tags: compiz, ubuntu-netbook, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application windows do not fit on the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14210/application-windows-do-not-fit-on-the-screen)

i have a netbook with 1024x568 resolution. But some windows don't fit to the screen.
They are to big.

How to change that

Comment: What do you mean?  Can't they just be resized to full screen?